# MYSQL: How to get specific data on table1 and get the latest data on table2 and table3

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table 1: tblemployee**

```
+------------+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
| EmployeeID | LastName | FirstName | ID_SC | ID_ES |
+------------+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
| 100000000  | Vallente | Rhea Mae  | 7     | 2     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
| 100000001  | Margallo | Matt      | 7     | 2     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
```

**Table 2: tblbadge**

```
+---------+------------+--------------+--------+------+
| BadgeNo | EmployeeID | Deactivation | ID_Rem | ID_S |
+---------+------------+--------------+--------+------+
| 1111111 | 100000001  | 2015-01-02   | 9      | 2    |
+---------+------------+--------------+--------+------+
| 2222222 | 100000001  | 2014-01-02   | 9      | 2    |
+---------+------------+--------------+--------+------+
```

**Table 3: tblemployeeactivity**

```
+------------+------------+---------------+-------+
| EmployeeID | ADate      | AttritionDate | ID_AT |
+------------+------------+---------------+-------+
| 100000001  | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-02    | 1     |
+------------+------------+---------------+-------+
| 100000001  | 2014-01-01 | 2014-01-02    | 1     |
+------------+------------+---------------+-------+
```

**Output Plan:**

```
+------------+----------+-----------+-------+-------+---------+--------------+--------+------+------------+---------------+-------+
| EmployeeID | LastName | FirstName | ID_SC | ID_ES | BadgeNo | Deactivation | ID_Rem | ID_S | ADate      | AttritionDate | ID_AT |
+------------+----------+-----------+-------+-------+---------+--------------+--------+------+-----------------------+----+-------+
| 100000001  | Margallo | Matt      | 7     | 2     | 1111111 | 2015-01-02   | 9      | 2    | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-02    | 1     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-------+-------+---------+--------------+--------+------+------------+---------------+-------+
```

Question: How can the lastest `BadgeNo` and `AttritionDate` in one query assume that the `tblemployee` is linked to `tblemployeeactivity` and same goes with `tblemployee` and `tblbadge` however `tblbadge` and `tblemployeeactivity` is not link together in SQL.

I have to get the employee's full details on `tblemployee` and fetch the latest data on  each table (`tblbadge` & `tblemployeeactivity`), Please see output plan, TIA.

> PS. Also I have to filter `AttritionDate` by `Year` and `Month`

Comment: `SELECT a.*, b.BadgeNo, b.Deactivation, b.ID_Rem, b.ID_S, c.ADate, c.AttritionDate, c.ID_AT
FROM tblemployee a,
     (SELECT BadgeNo, Deactivation, ID_Rem, ID_S FROM tblbadge WHERE EmployeeID = a.EmployeeID ORDER BY Deactivation DESC LIMIT 1) b,
     (SELECT ADate, AttritionDate, ID_AT FROM tblemployeeactivity WHERE EmployeeID = a.EmployeeID ORDER BY AttritionDate DESC LIMIT 1) c` Probably not the best way, but give that a shot.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'a.EmployeeID' in 'where clause'

The `a.EmpoyeeID` is not recognized in the where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query works to generate the desired result:

```
SELECT e.employeeid, e.lastname, e.firstname, e.id_sc, e.id_es,
       q1.badgeno, q1.deact, q1.id_rem, q1.id_s, 
       q2.adate, q2.attritiondate, q2.id_at
FROM tblemployee e
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT b.badgeno, b.employeeid, MAX(b.deactivation) AS deact, b.id_rem, b.id_s
     FROM tblbadge b
     GROUP BY b.employeeid) q1
     ON q1.employeeid = e.employeeid
 INNER JOIN
    (SELECT a.employeeid, MAX(a.adate) AS adate, a.attritiondate, a.id_at
     FROM tblemployeeactivity a
     GROUP BY a.employeeid) q2
     ON e.employeeid = q2.employeeid
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64a64a/17

Comment: It worked, It literally save my a**, Thank you so much i'll just tweak the SQL for some data filtration.